# Unwanted edge around image used in a plane

Tags: import, transparency

I have a problem with the imported image. as you can see the left picture is transparent and looks ok, but when I import it as image as Plane it gets an orange edge and I want to fix it but I don't even know why its there?

[image]

these are the nodes of the image as plane

[image]

Comment: Do you have the material that the image is using set to Shadeless, or is it receiving light and shadow?

Comment: I upload a pic with the nodes. I add an emission shader, because it is very dark in the scene

Comment: Use the emission shader instead of the diffuse shader, then get rid of the add shader.

Answer (score 1):

You should make the emission shader aware of the Alpha information from the image. At present indeed, the antialiased border of the globe is emitting as it was fully opaque.

You can do so by connecting the Alpha socket to the Strength input of the emission shader, and adding a "Math>Convert" node in the middle, set to multiply by 0.8.

[image: transparent emission]

(in your setup, the second - half transparent - stripe would have wrongly appeared completely white)

[ As cegaton says, however, for your application the `diffuse` and `add` shaders can be removed altogether: your globe isn't supposed to diffuse received light. ]